# Set up transparent proxy in front of explicit proxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, squid

I need to run a bunch of applications on an Ubuntu 14.04 server that is behind a corporate proxy. Unfortunately, those applications don't support corporate proxies.

I have heard that this might be possible with a local transparent proxy, such as Squid. Is that the case? How can I do that?

I have also tried proxychains, but no success:

```
$ proxychains curl http://google.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| google.com 
|D-chain|-<>-147.204.6.136:8080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--denied
|DNS-response|: google.com does not exist
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

Thanks for any help.